# after I upgraded my angular application from angular 5.2 to the latest. ng build produces this ERROR

Tags: angular

ERROR in ./src/styles.css (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./src/styles.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
SyntaxError

> (60:29) Unknown word
>
> 58 | .quiet {
>
> 59 |   text-decoration: underline;
>
> 60 |   display: inline-block; // to force underline on form button
>
> 61 |   color: #0066cc;
>
> 62 |   cursor: pointer;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its due to this line

`60 | display: inline-block; // to force underline on form button`

the `//` is not acceptable as a comment in css use `/* */` instead.